# Ajax in PartialView, asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Доброго времени суток.

Мне необходимо из PartialView вызвать Ajax скрипт на загрузку данных

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changed(data) {
    $.Ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetDepsAsync", "Employees")',
        data: { id: data },
        success: function(result){
            operate(data);
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

Но, в PartialView не работает секция скриптов `@section scripts {}`

Есть ли способ выполнить Ajax запрос из PartialView?

Comment: К тому же у меня ошибка `$.Ajax({`. Надо поменять на `$.ajax({`. Несколько раз на эти грабли наступил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дизайн фреймворка таков, что секции не работают в частичных представлениях. Asp.Net MVC заставляет представления (Views) быть ответственными за включение необходимых скриптов. Т.о. частичные представления (Partial Views) не должны быть ответственны за это.

Вы можете разместить секцию с необходимыми скриптами в основном представлении.

Также, вы можете создать свой `HtmlHelper`, чтобы добавить для частичных представлений аналогичную функциональность. Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433531/using-sections-in-editor-display-templates)